# Stop user registration on wordpress websites

Tags: php, wordpress

I have few WordPress websites with disabled registration, but still, I can see people are registering as admin, after a while, they reset the password and log in to the admin panel.. as I can see some fishy things on my server. How can I secure my websites from this kind of registration? the URL `mydomain.comwp-login.php?action=register` says disabled and redirecting to the login page.

Answer (score 3):

Setting -> General -> uncheck "Anyone can register"

Answer (score -1):

After successful registration, Wordpress immediately calls 'user_register' hook. You can perform a task there.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
  /** Here You can disable user's status or change user's credentials on the behalf of '$user_id' so that it cannot be logged into your system. You can remove the user as well. */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are comfortable with editing your theme's `function.php` then these scripts will help:

**Disable all user registrations:**

If your site is not handling any memberships and you want to totally disable the user registrations, then you can add this script in your active themes function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_pre_insert_user_data', 'disable_user_registrations', 10, 2 );
function disable_user_registrations ($data, $update) {
    if( !$update ) {
        return [];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This will throw an error: 'Not enough data to create this user.'

**Disable specific user roles:**

For example, disable user registrations with `administrator` role:

```
add_filter( 'wp_pre_insert_user_data', 'disable_user_registrations_for_role', 10, 4 );
function disable_user_registrations_for_role ($data, $update, $userId, $userdata) {
    if( !$update && !empty($userdata['role']) && $userdata['role'] == 'administrator' ) ) {
        return [];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

**Disable specific usernames:**

If you would like to disable registrations with specific usernames such as `admin`, then you can use below code:

```
add_filter( 'illegal_user_logins', 'disable_user_registrations_with_usernames' );
function disable_user_registrations_with_usernames () {
    return ['admin'];  //disables anyone registering with the username admin
}
```